# How can I combine each value from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing a simple dice roll app and I have the following object:

```js
die = [
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [6]
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [1] 
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [5] 
  }
]
```

I would like to get every `score` and combine them into one value so I can see the total of every score from this array.

Like this: `6+1+5`

How can I achieve this?

What I tried:

```
total = 0;

this.die.forEach((die) => {
  die.score.forEach((score) => {
    this.total += score;
  });
});
```

I'm getting NaN

Edit: I made an error in my object

```js
die = [
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [6]
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [1] 
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [5] 
  }
]

total = 0;

this.die.forEach((die) => {
  die.score.forEach((score) => {
    this.total += score;
  });
});

console.log(total)
```

Comment: Don't you want a reduce function for this? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Comment: Shouldn't this `this.total += score;` not be `total += score;`?

Comment: How are you getting NaN? `die.score.forEach` should throw an error

Comment: @adiga I'm using TypeScript

Comment: With the updated input, your code should work fine as it is

Comment: Why are you using `forEach` for `die.score`

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik because score is an array of numbers

Comment: Created a snippet with your code and it works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two `.reduce()` methods, the inner-most `reduce()` can be used to get the sum of all the elements in your `score` array, and the outer most `reduce()` can be used to sum all the results produced by the inner-most `reduce()`:

```js
const die = [{ofWhat:6,score:[6]},{ofWhat:6,score:[1]},{ofWhat:6,score:[5]}];

const total = die.reduce(
    (sum, {score}) => 
      sum+score.reduce((innerSum, n) => innerSum + n, 0), 0);
    
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
        let die = [
          {
            ofWhat: 6,
            score: [6]
          },
          {
            ofWhat: 6,
            score: [1] 
          },
          {
            ofWhat: 6,
            score: [5] 
          }
        ];
        let sum = 0;
        die.forEach(i => {
            i.score.forEach(val => {
                sum += val;
            });
        });
        console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a reducer

```js
die = [
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 6
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 1 
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 5 
  }
]


console.log(die.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc += curr.score;
  return acc;
}, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are taking each object from array with `this.die.forEach`, the content of object can be accessed like a normal object: `object.property`

```js
die = [
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 6
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 1 
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 5 
  }
]


total = 0;

this.die.forEach((obj) => {
    this.total += obj.score;
});

console.log("total score from die array: " + total)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in my object the score is actually an array of number

Answer (score 1):

```js
var die = [{
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 6
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 1
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 5
  }
];
var sum = 0;
die.forEach(element => {
  sum += element.score;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
die = [
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 6
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 1 
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: 5 
  }
]

const total = die.reduce((acc,curr) => acc+curr.score,0)
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this this by adding up all the `die.score` values.

*Updated to use arrays (after the question was updated to use arrays)*

If there is always just one array item, you can suffice with adding up each `die.score[0]` value.
Here we calculate 6+1+5 = 12:

```js
var die = [
  { ofWhat: 6, score: [6] },
  { ofWhat: 6, score: [1] },
  { ofWhat: 6, score: [5] }
]

var total = 0;

this.die.forEach((obj) => {
  total += obj.score[0];
});

console.log(total);
```

Or if there can be multiple values in each array, you'll need to iterate the inner array as well.
Here we calculate 6+6+1+5 = 18:

```js
var die = [
  { ofWhat: 6, score: [6, 6] },
  { ofWhat: 6, score: [1] },
  { ofWhat: 6, score: [5] }
]

var total = 0;

this.die.forEach((obj) => {
  obj.score.forEach((value) => {
    total += value;
  });
});

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
let die = [
    {
      ofWhat: 6,
      score: 6
    },
    {
      ofWhat: 6,
      score: 1 
    },
    {
      ofWhat: 6,
      score: 5 
    }
 ],sum=0;

die.forEach(x=> sum += x.score);
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
this.die.forEach((d) => {
  this.total += d.score;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use score[0]. 'score' is an array.

```js
  var  die = [
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [6]
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [1] 
  },
  {
    ofWhat: 6,
    score: [5] 
  }
];
 

   
total = 0;

this.die.forEach((obj) => {
    this.total += obj.score[0];
});

console.log("total score from die array: " + total)
```